# GridView Header Fixed and column Freezing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, html, gridview

I have browsed in allmost all the sites but didnt get proper solution. My question is on Fixing Grid View header and freezing the column. Most of the sites say that the browser doesnt supports, well i have tried my own code and also copied few codes from other sources but its not working. I tried jquery,css style both. Please give the solution.

Comment: Jquery and CSS will solve this problem only to some extend. There will be problems with browser. I have faced many issues like this. But I was able to solve this through a 3rd party dll. If you are ready to use such dlls I will provide you the link.

Comment: @ElegantCoder well even i tried 3rd party dll of ideasparks codeplex coolgrid view but it isnt trustworthy so i didnt add it as my extension. but one of my other developer hav tried that but resulted same.. NO Solution

Comment: @ElegantCoder u can share the link though

Comment: I have tried the same. CoolGridview, It is working perfecly. My customer is using it for more than 3 months and no complaints till now.

Comment: @ElegantCoder okie... will try it. If you have any other solution then please share it.

Comment: i got solution for fixed header. i used javascript code and jquery plugins.

Comment: Please share the solution.

Comment: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/11/jquery-fixed-header-scrollable-gridview.html try this link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wrote jQuery plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, it can be apply to GridView.
see the image:

[image]

look the website: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Supported Browsers

- Internet Explorer 7, 8 (IE 9 Compatibility)
- Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112)
- Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 Preview
- Google Chrome(23.0.1271.64 m)
- Mozilla Firefox (16.0.2)
- Apple Safari (5.1.7)